# Temporarily set DbContext's CommandTimeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

I know I can set the DbContext's CommandTimeout for all queries with something like this:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext() : base("YourConnectionString")
    {
        // Get the ObjectContext related to this DbContext
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

        // Sets the command timeout for all the commands
        // to 2 min instead of the default 30 sec
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
    }
}
```

However, I want to keep the default 30 sec, except for one single method that takes a bit longer.

How should I change this for this single query?

I did try to use:

```
public void doSomething(){
    // The using had another reason, but in this case it also
    // automatically disposes of the DbContext
    using(IMyDbContext = delegateDbContext()){
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)usingDb).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;

        ... // myQuery
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly, until I run my UnitTest with a Mock-DbContext (and yes, I did set my delegate to this Mock-DbContext). It gives me an `InvalidCastException`:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'Castle.Proxies.FakeMyDbContextProxy' to type
'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're relying on an implementation detail (the fact that your `IMyDbContext` also implements `IObjectContextAdapter`) that you're not supposed to know about. In your unit test, the `IMyDbContext` instance is actually a proxy generated by the mocking framework, and doesn't implement `IObjectContextAdapter`.

Since the `CommandTimeout` wouldn't make sense for this fake `DbContext`, I suggest you try to cast and set the `CommandTimeout` only if the cast succeed:

```
var objectContextAdapter = usingDb as IObjectContextAdapter;
if (objectContextAdapter != null)
    objectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

This way, the `CommandTimeout` will be set in the real execution environment, but not in the unit test (which doesn't matter, since the mock doesn't actually query the DB)

---

EDIT: actually, a better and cleaner option would be to modify `IMyDbContext` to expose a way to set the `CommandTimeout`:

```
interface IMyDbContext
{
    ...

    int CommandTimeout { get; set; }
}


class MyDbContext : IMyDbContext
{
    ...

    public int CommandTimeout
    {
        get { return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout; }
        set { ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = value; }
    }
}
```

And now you can just do:

```
usingDb.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

without worrying about the actual type of the context. The mocking framework would just generate a dummy implementation for this property.

Comment: About your Edit: It's giving me the following error: `"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CommandTimeout.get'"` on the `ObjextContext.CommandTimeout` in the MyDbContext property.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, ah, that must because `IObjectContextAdapter` is implemented explicitly, so `ObjectContext` is not recognized as a member of `this`. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

And to touch on the original question of setting the Timeout for a single statement. The straight-forward approach is sometimes the best. Assuming you've exposed the CommandTimeout as suggested above (great idea), then in your function:

```
var originalTimeout = _dbContext.CommandTimeout;
_dbContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
// do something relevant
_dbContext.CommandTimeout = originalTimeout;
```

Comment: This is indeed exactly how I use it right now. I use the code of [@ThomasLevesque's Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25075992/1682559) and temporarily save the old value so I can set and reset the CommandTimeout. Upvoted for having the exact same implementation as I have. :)